# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'am using Oracle 11g
I got this error when I use query:

```
select count(*) from potluck;
```

So when I use:

```
select count(*) from "potluck";
```

every is okie...
Please tell me why?
Thank you

Comment: Someone created the table with a quoted, and therefor case-sensitive, name - `create table "potluck" ...`.  When a table has such a name the only way to reference it is with a quoted name using the same case as in your second example.  If possible, rename the table to have a non-quoted name.

Comment: And also change all the programs that are referring that table after renaming it to non-quoted name.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63813/why-does-this-simple-select-statement-require-quotes/63814#63814