# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:14 cannot recognize input near ''default'' '.' ''sales_withcomma'' in join source

Tags: oracle, hive, virtual-machine

I am running the below commands in Hive and have already imported the table 'sales_withcomma' however still now working

SELECT * FROM 'default'.'sales_withcomma'

ALTER TABLE sales_withcomma SET SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'

Comment: "Still not working". Are we supposed to guess what that means ? Is there an error message ? If so... what is it ? Please provide as much info as possible

Comment: I don't know Hive, but - are you sure you should enclose schema and table name into single quotes? In Oracle, we enclose *strings* into them. I'd try `select * from default.sales_withcomma`.

Comment: The ALTER syntax seems correct, can ditch the quotes and try for the select query. Try:  `ALTER TABLE default.sales_withcomma SET SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' `and then `select * from default.sales_withcomma` this should work ideally if the table exist and the data is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes, not single quotes around tables/schemas. But using quotes is a bad practice for tables (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718685/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-oracle) question for an explanation why that is the case). This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM default.sales_withcomma;
```

Comment: Koen, I'd say that it isn't about UPDATE but really ALTER TABLE; there's that ALTER TABLE ... SET SERDE *thing* in Hive (see e.g. https://understandingbigdata.com/hive-alter-table/); SERDE stands for "serialization and deserailization (...) which tells how we should read and write the data".

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks I wasn't aware of that. I have removed it from my answer.